# Authorise Pinterest App

Tags: api, pinterest

I have added a collaborator for my Pinterest app, however, when accessing the colaberators account and clicking on the application there is no 'authorise' button or anything similar. The "You still need at least 1 collaborator to authorize your app before you can submit" warning still shows on the collaberators account. 
Ant help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had the same problem. You need to at least add two co-workers, one as collaborator and one as tester. These must be different people. And then, after some while (!) the authorize button has appeared.

The co-workers need to accept the invitation as well, of course.

After submitting, it will take some weeks (!) until you get the approval.

Comment: Do you know how long the approval process is after you submit the app?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have tried everything but no luck. Can you guide me on how much time takes for Authorize button to appear?

Comment: @AxelAmthor How do you send the invitation to the co-workers? Does pinterest send the invitation automatically after you add their account names in the page for the app (the same page that shows that app id and secret) ?

Comment: @Dimitry  It will not take more than 5 minutes for showing submit to review button

Comment: It's been more than 10 min and still nothing. Yeah Pinterest su***. This whole thing has been extremely confusing and difficult, they need to fire some people.

Comment: during this process, can you do anything at all with the app id?

Comment: Facebook is another fan of creating a confusing system. It's workable but incredibly over-complicated and unnecessary. Pinterest is no exception. Twitter on the other hand have nailed it.

Comment: It took my app 7 weeks to be approved by Pinterest. During this period the 'authorised' users that I had manually added could use the system but it was not available for everyone to use.

Comment: Pinterest have really bad support, I submitted an app for approval about ~40 days ago still not approved, today I deleted the app and created a new app and when I add collaborator (after following each other) seems like it's not adding collaborators and submitting app for review "Submit" button is also not working, looking into Networks tab it gives response 500 Bad Gateway - don't know what's the issue. I'd never use again (RIP)

Answer (score 3):

I had issue. By reading and following accepted answer, I waited 5 weeks and still submit for review button was not there.

What I did was I authorise my app for code which later I used for getting access token.

Once I successfully authorised my app using below authorisation URL the "Submit for review button " appeared in a second.

Authorisation URL:

https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8000&scope=write_public read_public&state=abcdefg

Use your client_id to authenticate to your app. Once you are done with that you can see the "Submit For review button" after refreshing the browser.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

for those who have this problem, note that you have to test your application before you could autorize or send to revision,

You need 3 Pinterest account, or 2 friends

register one as developer and another as tester

then, with the secret key and the app id, put it on your client application

after that, test the login,

finnaly go back to your pinterest app and the button for "send to revision" you wiil find it enabled,

Comment: unable to add collaborators :( when clicking "save" button, it says "saved" but after refreshing it still empty with no collaborators. don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that you are using same App ID and App secret in your application which is in developer pinterest app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick 2019 year update:

- You need two pinterest accounts, they should be following each other
  and should be collaborators in the APP.
- Have a ssl protected call back url, they only accept https urls.
- Finally all collaborators should authorize the app through your
  application/site. For this you need to already have the pinterest sdk
  integrated in your project.

Now you can submit the app for review.