# Can't make Pinterest app for api

Tags: api, pinterest

I have added a collaborator for my Pinterest app, however, when accessing the collaborators account and clicking on the application there is no **'Authorize'** button or anything similar. It keeps showing "You're almost ready! You still need at least 1 collaborator to authorize your app before you can submit.", I have done lots of research but I can't now find an answer to solve the problem. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150709/authorise-pinterest-app Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It means you should follow oauth flow to authorize one user. Check out "Authentication" section in https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check it out