# How to authorize app on Pinterest Developers?

Tags: pinterest

I am trying to create a Pinterest API and am following their steps at https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/?  ...and one of their steps is to create a Pinterest app, so that's what I'm doing. The problem is I keep getting the message "You're almost ready! You still need at least 1 collaborator to authorize your app before you can submit." I looked at [Authorise Pinterest App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150709/authorise-pinterest-app) and added two collaborator's, one as a Developer and one as a Tester, but it still doesn't work. So how can I authorize the Pinterest app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150709/authorise-pinterest-app Please check my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

An "authorize app" button appears some 1-2 days later. You will have to use that account to authorize the app and then it starts working